# Javassist CtMethod.make() gives "syntax error" on array initialization using empty brackets

Tags: arrays, syntax, syntax-error, brackets, javassist

I am using Javassist to build a runtime class. I am creating a CtMethod:

```
CtMethod m = CtMethod.make(constructMethodSource, bclass);
```

Inside "constructMethodSource" is this line which is a legitimate line of Java code:

```
java.lang.Object[] args = new java.lang.Object[] {};
```

With that, make() throws a syntax error:

```
[source error] syntax error near "bject[] {};"
```

I played with it and instead initialized my empty array a different way:

```
java.lang.Object[] args = new java.lang.Object[0];
```

That made Javassist happy but I'm wondering why does Javassist choke on the first line? Is that a known limitation or a bug or am I doing something foolish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked into this, the best answer I can come up with is that this is a bug of omission. According to the documentation it "should work", but it doesn't. Luckily the workaround is trivial, simply initialize your arrays with "new Object[0];".

Answer (score 0):

http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html (section 4.7) says:
Array initializers, a comma-separated list of expressions enclosed by braces { and }, are not available unless the array dimension is one.

Comment: Thank you. What array dimension is "new Object [] {}"? I would think that was a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't think about that much actually. It seems like that should work, as it is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @DataN00bleus & DziNeIT: I would say it's still an implementation limitation or a bug. Because as soon as you put something in the array the expression compiles. It's just for the special case of empty array initialization.